# can I pan individual howler.js sprites?

Tags: javascript, howler.js

It seems that a single howler.js (v2.02) sprite file can only be given one stereo location? So how can I have a stereo piano where 88 notes are set left to right like on an electronic keyboard? I'm trying to avoid 88 mp3 files.

I did try setting pan at the point where play is actuated but that only works if playing one note at a time.

Perhaps you can have two identical sprite files, one left and one right, and be able to set a mix of left and right for each note - OR - be able to wrap each sprite in a new Howl, but I think I'm clutching at straws.

Relevant code as follows; it works well with no panning:

```
    var pnoArray = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < 88; i++) {

        pnoArray[i] = [ i * 4000, 3850 ];
    }
    pnoSound = new Howl( {  src: [ 'SpriteTest1.mp3' ], sprite: pnoArray } );
```

Mousedown event:

```
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        controls.enabled = false;
        SELECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
        SELECTED.rotation.x = SELECTED.rotation.x + 0.03; //key action

        playing = pnoSound.play( [SELECTED.number] );

        container.style.cursor = 'auto';
    }
```

MouseUp event:

```
    if ( INTERSECTED ) {
        SELECTED.rotation.x = SELECTED.rotation.x - 0.03; //key action

        if( !sustain ) {

           pnoSound.pause( playing );
        }
        SELECTED = null;
    }
```